# Why does POST 'backend endpoint' 400 (Bad Request) error is occured?

Tags: reactjs, axios, vite

the error is catching in this piece of code:

```
 const handleTokenRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "backend endpoint here",
        {
          username: 1,
          password: 1,
          phone: formData.phoneNumber,
          verification_code: otp,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const accessToken = response.data.access;
        const refreshToken = response.data.refresh;

        loginUser(accessToken, refreshToken);
      } else {
        console.error("Token request failed. Something went wrong!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during token request:", error);

      if (error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
        console.error("Invalid verification code or user not found");
      }
    }
  };
```

first issue: POST 'backend enpoint' 400 (Bad Request)

second issue:

Error during token request:
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Request failed with status code 400"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
:
{data: {…}, status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=08b8f510:1204:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=08b8f510:1434:7)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error

i tried to fix this issue by myself but i couldn't, i had asked from chatgpt about it too but it was without results too, asked from blackbox ai and it didn't help too

Answer (score 0):

Have a try of setting **withCredentials:true** in the axios request.